# SQLDeveloper does not display full script output

Tags: xml, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create an xml document in oracle-sql using sql/xml.
I have my script ready but when I run it it displays only a small portion on the output.

```
<NBA><DIVISION ID="East"><FIRSTNAME>Jeffrey</FIRSTNAME><LASTNAME>Teague</LASTNAM
```

How can I get the whole output and also how can I write the xml output to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, add

```
set long 32767
```

before your query. That controls how much of long, CLOB and XMLType columns (and some other types) are displayed. The default is only 80 characters, which is what you are currently seeing.

[Read more in the SQL*Plus documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG088), much of which also applies to SQL Developer.

In 11g and [12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG088) SQL*Plus you can go up to 2000000000 bytes, so the maximum amount you'll actually see depends on the version of Oracle and SQL Developer you are using. If your XML is more than 32k, try setting long to that number and see if it complains. You will also need to `set linesize` to a large enough value to stop it wrapping, and you might hit a limit on that first. Or on the amount of RAM available, as the documentation mentions.

If you want to write the output to a file on your client machine, you can [spool the output](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_six.htm#i1082570). You can also run the query as a query (not a script) and save the results frmo the query result grid - but that isn't necessarily helpful if your script is doing other things as well. If you want to write to a file on the server you will need to use PL/SQL (see the `utl_file` package).

Comment: well this is still to small. Also spooling seems to ouput the same thing small portion. can the `utl_file` package output the whole thing to a local file?

Comment: `utl_file` can only write to a file on the database server - to a directory object. (That can in theory be a remote fielsystem mounted from elsewhere, including your PC, but you're unlikely to have that set up).

Comment: Yeah I just read the documentation. The database is 12c so I can go higher.